# @Html.checkboxfor - Get checkbox value using id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

In my application, user has a choice to check or uncheck a field "Right". I could able to set the model values to the checkbox using @html.checkboxfor

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Right, new { id="right"})
```

Can someone help me how to get the value using the id.
For now i am using $("#right").val() to get the value. But it is not working. Someone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please post some sample code.

Comment: There is no value associated with checkbox, thus `$("#right").val()` is returning nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
 $("#right").prop('checked')
```

OR

```
$("#right").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me to get @Html.CheckBoxFor status using JS .. Thanks kikyalex

> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IA.InProcess, new { @id = "cbinPro"
>   })
>
> alert($("#cbinPro").is(":checked"));

Answer (score 1):

You can get the checked checkbox values like this

```
$('input:checkbox[name=right]').each(function() {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
  alert($(this).val());});
```

Please check this [Link](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/asp-net-mvc-displaying-and-retrieving-values-from-a-list-of-checkboxes/). It can be helpful