# HTML.Checkboxfor to Toggle button HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Is there anyway to convert the @HTML.Checkboxfor into toggle html button?
I have refer the toggle button style from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Currently its working by using :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsEnabled, new { @checked = "checked", @Name = "DelegateChkBox" })
```

Changed to:

```
    <td class="slider-td">
         <label class="switch">
            <input name="DelegateChkBox" id="IsEnabled" type="checkbox" value="true" data-val-required="The IsEnabled field is required." data-val="true" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
          </label>
   </td>
```

The toggle button only works and postback to controller if it's CHECKED:
[image]

else it won't postback to controller by default UNCHECKED :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly not related, but you have a property named `IsEnabled` but then you change the `name` attribute to `DelegateChkBox` which will never bind to your model (you should never change the `name` attribute). And you never set the `checked` attribute - that is done correctly by the `CheckBoxFor()` method based on the value of `IsEnabled`.

Comment: And unchecked checkboxes do not submit a value, which is why the `CheckBoxFor()` method generates 2 inputs - a `<input type="checkbox" .. value="true" />` and a `<input type="hidden" value="false" />`

Comment: And you can use `@Html.CheckBox()` rather than manually creating your html - you just need to modify the css selectors

Comment: Try [Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) plugin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based from some experiments and findings, I found that you need to include hidden field generated by the helper (`Html.CheckBoxFor`) as shown by styling below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s;
}

/* include generated hidden field here */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* include generated hidden field here */
input[type="checkbox"]:focus + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

/* include generated hidden field here */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

View usage example (just change `<input type="checkbox" />` to `@Html.CheckBoxFor`):

```
<label class="switch">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsEnabled)
    <div class="slider round">
    </div>
</label>
```

To ensure the checkbox is being checked in client-side before doing postback, you can use jQuery code below:

```
// change event may modified to other events
$("#IsEnabled").change(function () {

    // check if checkbox is being checked
    // taken from /a/23007488 by Alexandru Chichinete
    if ($("#IsEnabled").is(":checked"))
    {
        // enable form submit
    }
});
```

Demo example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyJ5OY)

References:

[Styling checkboxes in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850298/styling-checkboxes-in-mvc-4)

[How can I apply a CSS style to Html.CheckBoxFor in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696300/how-can-i-apply-a-css-style-to-html-checkboxfor-in-mvc-5)

[@Html.checkboxfor - Get checkbox value using id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007423/html-checkboxfor-get-checkbox-value-using-id)

Comment: All thats needed is to change the `+` (adjacent) selector to a `~` (siblings) selector in the 3 relevant classes (and no javascript is required)

Comment: AFAIK, adjacent selectors just a bare minimum here (of course siblings selectors also work too), and the JS part only used if OP wants to submit form based on checked value.

Comment: thanks alot @tetsuya yamamoto for this solution! you rocks!

Comment: Superb! @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple, I have implemented in my project.
You just need to keep the value of checkbox in a HiddenFor.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsEnabled, new{@id = "DelegateChkBox"})
```

Then display your Toggle button in the page. For example,

```
 <td class="slider-td">
   <label class="switch">
    <input name="DelegateChkBox" id="IsEnabled" type="checkbox" value="true" 
      data-val-required="The IsEnabled field is required." data-val="true" 
      data-bind="checked: IsEnabled">
    <div class="slider round"></div>
   </label>
 </td>
```

So now when user check/uncheck the checkbox, call a jquery method and assign the value to @Html.HiddenFor(..). That's it.

```
$('#IsEnabled').change(function(){
  if($(this).val()==true)
   {
    $('#DelegateChkBox').val(true);
   }
  else
   {
    $('#DelegateChkBox').val(false);
   }
})
```

Please check once this **if ($("this").is(":checked"))** instead **if($(this).val()==true)** and assign the value accordingly. Little busy, could not check my code :)

That's it. Now when you post back your page, you already set value to your IsEnabled field.

In Get method you have to do like the same. You just need to check the value of your HiddenFor() and take that value and assign to your HTML Toggle button in pageload event of js.

```
$(function() {
 if($('#DelegateChkBox').val()== true)
  {
   $('#IsEnabled').prop("disabled", false);
  }
 else
  {
   $('#IsEnabled').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

That's it. Please change the HTML accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i do tried with included HiddenFor() but the slider won't work ( can't slide to left or right ) . That's the thing i'm struggling after added HiddenFor(). Anyway i will keep trying, thanks alot!

Comment: @Edward.K That's why I mentioned "Please change the HTML accordingly". I didn't check your HTML Toggle button. U just need to check ur Toggle button and follow my steps. This is very easy way. Let me know after it work.

Comment: Thanks guys for your contribution, problem solved by using tetsuya yamamoto solution.